# Appcelerator ERROR | socket hang up

Tags: appcelerator

Tengo el siguiente problema al intentar compilar directamente en un Iphone o Android ( dispositivo fisico )

[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 68.30137s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[ERROR] :  socket hang up

Estoy probando con la ultima version del IDE de appcelerator y titanium 6.3.0

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Me auto respondo.
Esto error ocurre por un problema de red.

Cuando appcelerator realiza build, este realiza un request a los servidores de appcelerator( para validar cierta información), el cual , en mi empresa , se encontraba bloqueado. Comprobe lo anterior, probando directamente en otra red en la cual funciono correctamente.

Para saber lo anterior , utilice el siguiente comando "appc run -p ios -T "simulator" -l trace" , el cual me mostro el error de conexion a appcelerator.

Saludos.